# How to verify a button is clicked before another button executes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, button

Just like the title says I am trying to make sure one button is clicked before a second will execute. Here is what I have, right now I believe the calculateButtonWasClicked = true; is out of the second buttons scope so it always evaluates to false. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows;

namespace priceQuote
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        //Declaring Variable
        public bool calculateButtonWasClicked = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Disabling the unobtrusive data validation
            UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    }


        protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declaring Variables
            decimal salesPrice;
            decimal discountPercent;

            //Attempting to convert user input into decimal data types
            decimal.TryParse(salesPriceBox.Text, out salesPrice);
            decimal.TryParse(discountBox.Text, out discountPercent);

            //Calculating discount amount and assigning the value to a label
            decimal discountAmount = salesPrice * (discountPercent * .01m);
            discountAmountLabel.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");

            //Calculating total amount and assigning the value to a label
            decimal total = salesPrice - discountAmount;
            totalLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");

            //Changing variable from false to true
            calculateButtonWasClicked = true;
        }

        protected void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (calculateButtonWasClicked)
            {
                Session["salesPrice"] = salesPriceBox.Text;
                Session["discountAmount"] = discountAmountLabel.Text;
                Session["total"] = totalLabel.Text;

                //Redirecting to new page
                Response.Redirect("~/confirmation.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                calculateWarningLabel.Text = "Amounts need to be calculated first. Please click calculate button.";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do this on client side?

Comment: this is actually very simple ...the easy way would be to create a bool variable setting it's initial value to false, then set the other button.enable property initially to false.. then set the second button.Enabled = bool variable value meaning true or false also read up about PostBack or how to use an `UpdatePanel`

Comment: change this to Protected or Static `public bool calculateButtonWasClicked = false;` or assign it's value initially to a session variable.. so many ways to do this your main issue is being caused because of PostBack.. all button clicks trigger a postback.. learn JavaScript as well to handle this

Comment: Changing it to static worked. Thanks, MethodMan!